# Subharmonic function mean value inequality definitions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Say we define subharmonic functions as functions $f(x) \in C^0(\Omega)$ such that for any interior $x \in \Omega, \exists \rho>0$ such that for any $0<r<\rho$, 
$$ f(x) \leq \frac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)}f(y)dy. $$

How would we go about deducing the global mean value inequality, i.e.

$$ f(x) \leq \frac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)}f(y)dy, \forall B_r(x) \subset \Omega?$$

Here, $|B_r(x)|$ denotes the volume of $B_r(x)$.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Mollify $f$: $f^\epsilon(x):=(\eta^\epsilon * f)(x)$, where $\eta^\epsilon$ is the standard mollifier. Show that $f^\epsilon$ satisfies the same local mean value inequality. Since $f^\epsilon$ is smooth, you can conclude that $\Delta f^\epsilon \geq 0$, and so $f^\epsilon$ satisfies the global mean value inequality. Then send $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @Jeff without having worked out the details, that sounds like it would work. However it seems overly involved. Are there no simpler ways?

Comment: There may be other ways, but this is the simplest that comes to mind. It's not really all that involved if you are familiar with these ideas.